# How I can write better routers of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sonarqube, angular-routing

I have an AngularJS routes file in an ionic project, and I have a very large amount of routes, about a hundred. Is like the one below.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';  
  angular.module('application').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: 'menuController'
    })
    .state('app.signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
                controller: 'signupController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.user', {
        url: '/user',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/user.html',
                controller: 'userController'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/signup');
  });
})();
```

However, I want to do better to solve a high percentage of code duplication, which is shown on the sonar. I saw a model here https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y270 but I do not know how to get my code to this structure, or a way that can reduce the percentage of duplication, how can I do?

Comment: If want to reuse route config structure in order to create configs, you could write a function which accepts all the parameters needed and creates the config object, but I wouldn't recommend it. Routes should be clear and readability is more important than reusability in this case. If you're worried about your code length, any editor can collapse blocks of codes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest: what you are trying to fix is a perfectly valid code. This is some kind of configuration - so no wonder why SonarQube detects it as copy-paste. But this does not mean that you should fix something.

Instead, I would suggest you to configure SonarQube to ignore this specific file. You can do it in the administration settings of your project in SonarQube: "Analysis Scope > Duplications".

Please read the ["Narrowing the Focus"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreDuplications) documentation page to know more about this.

Comment: Thank you so much!